# Ignoring characters in field string in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I'm pulling a list of names from a database;

```
SELECT * FROM people ORDER BY name ASC
```

However, some of the names are like `[Mod]John`, and these are all at the end of the list instead of in alphabetical order, because of starting with `[`.

Is there a simple way to ignore the `[mod]` part when sorting my names, but still pull the entry? So I still have John in my list?

Do I need to sort them using PHP after pulling?

Comment: it looks like you use the word '[mod]' in the name to indicate that the user is a moderator, that is why you ended up in this situation . If mod is meant to be an attribute indicator, it is best to create a different field for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use (please check syntax):

```
SELECT *, replace(name, '[mod]', '') as sortname FROM people order by sortname ASC
```

But essentially use the *replace* function.

Answer (score 1):

Replace the [Mod] tag with an empty string:

```
ORDER BY REPLACE(name, '[Mod]', '')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it this way -- using `NOT LIKE` -- if you are attempting to exclude the names starting with '[mod]':

```
SELECT * FROM people WHERE name NOT LIKE '[mod]%';
```

Comment: Compare the 'not like' to `'[mod]%'` so `[mod]` (e.g.: `Word [mod] in a sentence`)  in the middle of a value is not accidentally excluded.

Comment: Fair statement.. Editied

Comment: Thank you for helping, my apologies for not explaining myself properly

Answer (score 0):

You omitted to mention what collation you are currently using. You also forgot to explain how you do want it sorted - do you want the results ordered as if the '[mod]' was not there? Or based on order of the characters in the ASCII table?

The '[' character (0x5B) comes before the lower case letters in ASCII, but after the upper case letters. So to sort based on the ASCII character code:

1. Use a case-sensitive sort
2. Sort by `lower(name) ASC
3. ORDER BY name LIKE '[mod]%' DESC, name ASC

If you just want to ignore it for sorting purposes:

```
ORDER BY REPLACE(name, '[mod]','') ASC
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use the MySQL `SUBSTRING_INDEX` function. e.g.

```
 ORDER BY SUBSTRING_INDEX(name,']',-1)
```

That's going to start at the end of the string, and look backwards until it finds the delimiter character, in this example, a right square bracket. When it finds the delimiter, it returns everything so far, up to (or back to) the delimiter. If the delimiter isn't found, then it returns the whole string.

We can test the expression in the SELECT list, to better observe the behavior, before including it in the ORDER BY.

As a demonstration:

```
SELECT t.name
     , SUBSTRING_INDEX(t.name,']',-1) AS x_mod
  FROM ( SELECT '[mod]john' AS name
         UNION ALL SELECT 'james'
         UNION ALL SELECT 'jude'
       ) t 
 ORDER BY 2
```

returns

```
name       x_mod   
---------  --------
james      james   
[mod]john  john    
jude       jude
```

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
SELECT * FROM people ORDER by REPLACE(name, '[mod]', '');
```

(This works in MySQL.)